# Is it possible to partially italicize the text of a QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I know how to italicize the entire text of a QTreeWidgetItem:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* elt = new QTreeWidgetItem(item);
QFont font = elt->font(0);
font.setItalic(true);
elt->setText(0, choice);
elt->setFont(0, font);
```

But is it possible to italicize only part of that text? (e.g. the first one or two words)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible with:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
QLabel *label = new QLabel("<i>italics</i>, <b>bold</b>, normal", treeWidget);
treeWidget->setItemWidget(item, 0, label);
```

but cleaner solution could be by using `QTreeView` and subclassing `QItemDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option by default. You need to set a `QItemDelegate` that is able to render HTML. See [this solution](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12709/#69207).